# How to run docker container with custom domain on localhost

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose, dockerfile, virtualhost

I usually using Docker for desktop and I need to work in multiple projects at the same time.

So I would like to setup separate project with separated URL like a virtual host on xampp.
For example project A = http://project-a.test, project B = http://project-b.test

I ever tried research and setup it separated port but still cannot map it as domain like above.

Is it possible to setup custom domain? if so, please explain how to set up via docker-compose.yml (and/or with Dockerfile) and apache server step by steps.
Thanks in advance.

This is example for my setup of project-a
here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    container_name: simplephp56
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ${DOCKER_FILE}
    ports:
      - "${HTTP_PORT}:80"
      - "${HTTPS_PORT}:443"
      - "25:25"
    volumes:
      - "${WORKING_DIR}:/var/www/html"
    restart: always
```

my .env

```
DOCKER_FILE=Dockerfile56
WORKING_DIR=./code
HTTP_PORT=8000
```

my 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@simplephp56.com
  ServerName simplephp56.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

my Dockerfile (named Dockerfile56)

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN buildDeps=" \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
  libicu-dev \
  libpng-dev \
  libjpeg-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libxml2-dev \
  libc-client-dev \
  libssh2-1-dev \
  libbz2-dev \
  redis-server \
  git \
  " \
  && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps \
  && pecl install ssh2 \
  && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
  && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
  && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) calendar iconv curl intl xml soap session mcrypt opcache pdo pdo_mysql mysqli mbstring json hash zip fileinfo xmlrpc xmlwriter bcmath ctype sockets ftp gd dom bz2 tokenizer \
  && docker-php-ext-enable intl xml json ssh2

COPY ./config/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Comment: You need some kind of reverse proxy. You can run an nginx container in docker and use it to map different hostnames to different ports/containers.

Answer (score 0):

I am running a similar setup. Most probably, the problem with your setup is that, you can listen on the same port only by a single application. You can setup multiple domains to resolve to `127.0.0.1 (a.k.a. localhost)` but you can't have multiple HTTP servers listening on the port `80`.

You can overcome this issue by listening on the port `80` with another proxy webserver container, and redirecting (or rewriting to be more precise) the requests to the actual containers according to the incoming request's hostname.

So,

1. Set the domains `project-a.test` and `project-b.test` to resolve to `127.0.0.1` in your `hosts` file.
2. Make the docker containers for `project-a.test` and `project-b.test` listen on port different than `80`.
3. Use something like [`nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) to rewrite requests to proper ports to actual containers.

Comment: I just edit my setup details for example project-a, please see if I have wrong some setup., thanks for your answer.